# Text node cannot appear in this state (Line 1, position 1)

Tags: c#, mono

I'm just starting to learn C#, and I am using Koding to develop (since I don't currently have access to my Ubuntu machine). I'm attempting to get the Hello World program to work, but the compiler I'm using (which is Mono) isn't taking it.

This is the code that I'm using for the program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
namespace ConsoleApplication1{
    class Program{
        static void Main(string[] args){
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I created a file, wrote the code, and attempted to compile it using `xbuild program.cs` but I got the error message `Text node cannot appear in this state (Line 1, position 1)`.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it the compiler, the OS, the code?

Comment: when I run it [here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php) it's working.  It's definitely valid code.

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't taking it"? What error does it spit out?

Comment: That error message smells XML-ish to me. Perhaps it's an error in the project file, or something like that.

Comment: The error is in the title, BradleyDotNet. Also, I am not using XML. I created a file, wrote the code, and attempted to compile it using "xbuild program.cs". My only other possibility is that I missed something when I installed the compiler (since I got Mono, but then also had to get xbuild to get it to compile).

Answer (score 0):

`xbuild` expects a project or solution file (which are xml format), not a c# source file. You should pass that (e.g. `xbuild program.sln`), or if you don't have one then invoke the compiler directly by `mcs program.cs` or similar.

PS: You should have mentioned the command line you used in the original question, instead of in a comment later.